# Non-modal or popup like window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to create a non-modal or pop-up window using jquery in JSP. I want to show user some detail information on separate window but without blocking main window. I don't wan to use new tab or browser window so basically like modal box but with ability to access main page too.

Comment: Yes. jQuery UI framework has a modal dialog, Bootstrap has a modal dialog, any many others (pretty much any UI framework worth looking into) comes with some kind of modal dialog functionality out of the box. You can usually configure them as to whether they block input with an overlay or not.

Comment: I just can't figure out, how implementing a simple show/hide element on a page would require a mega class library???

Comment: @Teemu: It doesn't, but I think a lazy question deserves a lazy answer. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvuv1ayk/), too!

Comment: @Cory I guess you're right with this ; ). CV and move on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have the modal window on screen and have the display property set to none. When you have an event that requires the window, just show it. You can also create the divs on the fly and then position them however you want. This should be a fairly simple solution and will not require any additional libraries or frameworks.